# Change gridview based on data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a website which is being developed in ASP.NET and C#. I have a page which currently contains two `Gridview`. First grid is for employees and second for managers. I split the data depedning on who is logged in. If manager is logged in he/she should see both grids and if employee logs in he/she should only see one grid. I have managed to get both of the grid but can't seem to figure out how to display them accordingly. My code is as follows;

```
public List<MyClass> GetData()
{
    string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();

    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyProcedure", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
            connection.Open();
            using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    MyClass mc = new MyClass();

                    mc.Id = reader["Id"].ToString();
                    mc.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    myList.Add(mc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return myList;
}
```

And to bind the data on the page I have the grids I do

```
MyClass list = new MyClass();

//Employee Grid  
GridView1.DataSource = list.GetData();
GridView1.DataBind();   

//Manager Grid
GridView2.DataSource = list.GetData();
GridView2.DataBind();
```

My `PROCEDURE` is very simple it checks if it's manager or employee and returns the relevant data. The procedure works as it's been tested already.

I can't seem to figure out how to go about displaying the grid for manager and employee. Would I need two different funtions?

Thanks in advance for all your help and support

Comment: Obviously, this code will bind both the grids with same data, either create two separate methods and call them individually or else, through your SP return both `employee` & `manager` details in two different result sets and modify your return type to have two lists, one for employee and other for manager. With this you can bind both grids with single method.

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks for the quick response. Would it b possible to provide a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current implementation, both grids will bind with same data, so for two different results(Employee & Manager) you can:-

1. Write two SPs (each SP fetching employee & manager records individually) and call them individually.
2. (***Preferred***) From your existing SP return two result-sets (one for employee & one for Manager), you can also set an `output parameter` to check if logged in user is Manager or Employee. Then in the same method, instead of returning `List<MyClass>` you can return a custom type which will have both list of employee as well as list of Manager like this:-

   ```
   public class EmployeeAndManager
   {
       public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
       public List<Employee> manager { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Finally in your method, Use [NextResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) method to fetch both results as shown below:-

```
public EmployeeAndManager GetData()
{
    //Your Rest Code
     EmployeeAndManager em = new EmployeeAndManager();
     List<MyClass> emp = new List<MyClss>();
     List<MyClass> man= new List<MyClss>();
     while(reader.Read())
     {
         MyClass mc = new MyClass();
         mc.Id = reader["Id"].ToString();
         mc.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
         emp.Add(mc);
     }
    reader.NextResult();
    while(reader.Read())
     {
         MyClass mc = new MyClass();
         mc.Id = reader["Id"].ToString();
         mc.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
         man.Add(mc);
     }
    em.employees = emp;
    em.manager= man;
    return em;
  }
```

Comment: I get the following error when I set the datasource for gridview `Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
`

Comment: Don't bind it directly bind it with properties like this: `GridView1.DataSource = list.GetData().employees;`

Comment: Right I got you. Thanks!! it works as expected you're a life saver